# Delete question from Ask Ubuntu and post it in U&L

Tags: discussion, questions, cross-posting

[I made a question in Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1495254/ubuntu-server-22-04-postfix-dovecot-error-postfix-smtpd-fatal-no-sasl-authenti) trying to solve an issue that I need for my work. I chose Ask Ubuntu because the server I'm working is Ubuntu 22.04 server.

But the question is 4 days old now, has only 19 views and zero interactions (comments, edits, etc).

I don't know how is Ask Ubuntu participation rate, mainly veteran and savvy users that are the most probable to be able to help me with my question.

I'm still trying to solve the issue, and I was thinking to delete the question in Ask Ubuntu and post it here in U&L, where I *may* have better chances to receive some responses.

Is it OK then to delete a question in some SE site and post it in another? And specifically from Ask Ubuntu to U&L, given that there's an overlapping scope that can be addressed in both sites.

Comment: Tangentially, another option (in case you weren't aware), you could add a bounty to the AU question to gain visibility for it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I already deleted in AU and posted here. I have the sensation that I would not get any help there (not that I'm blaming the AU community, as far as I've interacted there, I liked it), even with a bounty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to move a question from one StackExchange site to another, given that the question is on-topic on the site it is being moved to, and that the question only is "live" on a single site at any point in time.

You can do this in two ways:

1. Request migration of the question by flagging it for moderator attention.  The problem with this is that it may possibly take some time before a moderator sees the flag.  It's also possible that the moderator disagrees with you and decides not to migrate the question.  A migrated question will retain its creation date on the destination site.
2. Delete the question on the first site and create it anew on the second site.  An issue with this is that if you have any answer to your question, this action counts towards a question ban (a ban that exists to prevent users from asking questions and then immediately deleting their questions at the moment someone answers).

In any case, ensure that the question does not exist on more than one site at any point in time and that it is on-topic on the site where it is "live".

Comment: Thanks. I was going to delete in AU and post here yesterday, but then I though *"I'm not that sure if it's OK"* given that there's no permanent deletion. I thought of the flagging for migration but yay, as you mention it could be too much "bureaucracy". The fact that I received no feedback *at all* in AU and that I need to make the thing work ASAP makes me do the moving. It's been a while since a interact in AU and frankly my intuition tells me that I won't get any help there, at least with my present issue.